# How to open facebook share dialog in my app browser when FB app not installed in device. IOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Hello i am working on sharing and posting images,
so i have taken reference from below links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

If FB app installed then it working fine but it is not work when FB not installed.
I have did code but not able to open share dialog in my app when FB app not installed in device.
can any one suggest or help me where is problems?

I have did code below shared:

below my code-base:

```
        let photo = SharePhoto(
            image: imageSS,
            userGenerated: true
        )
        let content = SharePhotoContent()
        content.photos = [photo]
        
        let dialog = ShareDialog(
            fromViewController: self,
            content: content,
            delegate: nil
        )

        
        // Recommended to validate before trying to display the dialog
        do {
            try dialog.validate()
        } catch {
            // Handle error
        }
        
        dialog.mode = .automatic
        
        dialog.show()
```

Comment: Have you added the required values to your info.plist?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes i did it.